# Page areas in Mezzanine

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, mezzanine

I am new in Mezzanine CMS and i need to develop a company website using it.
The problem is that the home page has different sections or areas that i want to administrate using the admin. Areas like the team members or another describing the services.

Now i have a base page and a home template that extends it, and a page in the admin called home. I don't know how to edit the different contents of the page from the admin in a easy way.

It is possible to do this using Mezzanine or the only way is to edit the page as a unit?

Answer (score 0):

U can create your own page types. U may set plugins to the page or extra slots, and u may create models related to them like explained in there = >>  http://mezzanine.jupo.org/docs/content-architecture.html